# How to test Javascript that triggers 3rdparty cookies being set

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, cookies, browser-extension

I want to run automated tests that will execute a Javascript file. The JS calls a number of URLs through AJAX calls and image loads, each of which leads to the site being called dropping a cookie.

Since I cannot read those cookies with Javascript, I don't know whether I can actually test this script.

What is the best way of approaching this problem? Browser extensions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to replace the AJAX URLs with your own local mock sites that do nothing but verify that the cookies (or the trigger messages) are being sent properly.

Comment: Right, that would test the script. But I need to monitor whether the sites correctly drop their cookie. I have no control over what they do, and they are rather likely to change their implementation without me knowing.

Comment: So you have no control over these other sites, but you want to monitor their server-side state? I'm confused about your use case. Could you clarify "drop their cookie?"

Comment: I have implemented an opt-out mechanism that will allow users to opt-out of targeted advertising from multiple vendors. Each of the vendors has a different way of allowing opt outs, and I have no control over their implementation. If they decided to change their mechanism, I would never know.

Comment: Okay, but to reiterate, the only real way to know if these vendors are respecting the opt-out is to see if they stop *sending* the cookies. Cookies are just data passed with HTTP messages between clients and severs. One way to do it could be to have a dummy client with accounts under each vendor; if you opt-out that client and they still send a cookie with future requests, either they aren't respecting the opt-out or the opt-out protocol has changed. This could be complicated if vendors don't allow you to opt back in for further testing, though.

Comment: Opting out means they actually set a cookie that marks the user as having opted out. Since I cannot read their cookies, I have no way of checking the opt-out status.